# Animations in CSS cause lags on the site

Tags: bootstrap-4, css-animations

On the work in progress page we are trying to replicate a cloud-moving animation in CSS and we are working with bootstrap 4. However the animation does work but it causes lags on the site when you scroll down the site starting. If you scroll up and down the cursor seems to "lag behind the scrollbar" starting below the second table row. The test-site is: http://dev.thedesignfactory.ro/monster-fitness/html/

Here is our CSS for one cloud:

```
xxx .cloud1 {
opacity: 0;
width: 190px;
height: 80px;
top: 80px;
animation: cloud_anim 20s infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
will-change: transform;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
}
```

My co-developer states that it does not lag on his test-devices and computers, but only on mine, so I am not sure if there is any incompatibility, even though we use the same browsers. We tried to replicate the animation from this site: https://www.headspace.com/
As you can see the clouds move from left to right and cause no lags and they are done as well via CSS.

We are kind of clueless here and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question. Questions should be useful to future readers. Don't use external links that will change over time.

Comment: Looks fine on my system.  I do recommend you slow your clouds down though.  They seem too fast to me.

Comment: Looks fine on my system too, have you checked different browsers?

Comment: Hm that is really weird, in IE and Firefox it is smooth scrolling, but in chrome it lags even I have emptied all the cache. Also in incognito it is lagging in chrome.